# cython and pyinstaller issue

Tags: python, pyinstaller, cython

I have an odd issue with cython and pyinstaller.

My code compilation process used to work fine, then something changed on the MAC and I did some updates and now things aren't working...

Taking my code and simply using pyinstaller works fine - no errors.
Taking my code and converting to .so files with cython and running works fine - no errors.
Taking the .so files from cython and then running through pyinstaller does not work (it used to). I get the following error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/var/folders/95/mfn5xj2s59jgjjch0b8f5jbw0000gn/T/_MEIhKYuUp/WWS_Server.so, 2): Symbol not found: _Py_EnterRecursiveCall
  Referenced from: /var/folders/95/mfn5xj2s59jgjjch0b8f5jbw0000gn/T/_MEIhKYuUp/WWS_Server.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /var/folders/95/mfn5xj2s59jgjjch0b8f5jbw0000gn/T/_MEIhKYuUp/WWS_Server.so
```

Any ideas on where to look to solve this issue?

- Mac OS Darwin
- Cython version 0.29.22
- pyinstaller 4.2

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem was that my python had been upgraded to 3.9 which was causing problems. Moving back to 3.8 (pyenv) fixed the issue.